# How to create random string with multiple formats?

Tags: swift, random, stringwithformat

I need to create a random string with format which can convert any string(including parenthesis() to another color on swift: for example:

Hey (Hey) : First part 'Hey' is fine, but I want to change : (Hey) to a different color 
same goes if I choose another string

Hi (What's Up) ....

And tried the following

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 50)))

let color = UIColor(white: 0.2, alpha: 1)
let attributedTextCustom = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "(\(String())", attributes: [.font: UIFont(name:"AvenirNext-Medium", size: 16)!, .foregroundColor: color]))
attributedTextCustom.append(NSAttributedString(string: " (\(String())", attributes: [.font: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 12)!, .foregroundColor: UIColor.lightGray]))
label.attributedText = attributedTextCustom
```

Something like this is the behavior I am looking for (just for demostration...):

[image]

Comment: So you want to change the text colour of any string contained within parenthesis?

Comment: mmm format both parts of the "random whole string ". But in the case my string has the parentheses then it'll be a different color including the parentheses .

Comment: Please note that you're missing a `"` in the third line and that's the reason the text highlighting is broken in the question. I guess it's not reflecting your actual code, but did not take the liberty to correct it myself.

Comment: yes, I started to work it and try different approaches, corrected to my initial approach now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex `"\\((.*?)\\)"` to find the range of the word between the parentheses and add the color attribute to a `NSMutableAttributedString`:

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 50)))
let sentence = "Hello (Playground)"
let mutableAttr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: sentence, attributes: [.font: UIFont(name:"AvenirNext-Medium", size: 16)!, .foregroundColor: UIColor.black])

if let range = sentence.range(of: "\\((.*?)\\)", options: .regularExpression) {
    let color = UIColor(white: 0.2, alpha: 1)
    let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font: UIFont(name:"AvenirNext-Medium", size: 16)!, .foregroundColor: color]
    mutableAttr.addAttributes(attributes, range: NSRange(range, in: sentence))
    label.attributedText = mutableAttr
}
```